# Python Tkinter Grid Expand to window

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tkinter-layout

I have a notebook that I placed in grid (0;0). I want to the notebok to fill the entire screen even if its content (frames) would not fill the screen.

[image: screenshot]

```py
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # Widgets
        self.notebook = Notebook(self) #  <-- Widget I want to fill the window
        self.notebook.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.control_frame = ControlFrame(self)
        self.notebook.add(self.control_frame, text="Control")
```

```
class ControlFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.control_bar = ControlBar(self)
        self.control_bar.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.connect_btn = Button(self, text="Connect")
        self.connect_btn.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.log = Text(self, width=100)
        self.log.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `sticky` argument in you grid:

> The width of a column (and height of a row) depends on all the widgets
> contained in it. That means some widgets could be smaller than the
> cells they are placed in. If so, where exactly should they be put
> within their cells?
>
> By default, if a cell is larger than the widget contained in it, the
> widget will be centered within it, both horizontally and vertically.
> The master's background color will display in the empty space around
> the widget. In the figure below, the widget in the top right is
> smaller than the cell allocated to it. The (white) background of the
> master fills the rest of the cell.
>
> The sticky option can change this default behavior. Its value is a
> string of 0 or more of the compass directions nsew, specifying which
> edges of the cell the widget should be "stuck" to. For example, a
> value of n (north) will jam the widget up against the top side, with
> any extra vertical space on the bottom; the widget will still be
> centered horizontally. A value of nw (north-west) means the widget
> will be stuck to the top left corner, with extra space on the bottom
> and right.

So your code should look something like

```
self.notebook.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSWE')
```

If you need more information check out this [article](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @acw1668 for the hint!

I think the behaviour of the `ttk.Notebook` class is strange with the grid layout.
I manage to "solve" it using pack in the `App()` class.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.notebook = Notebook(self)  # <-- Widget I want to fill the window

        self.control_frame = ControlFrame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.control_frame, text="Control", sticky="NSWE")
        self.notebook.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)


class ControlFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.control_bar = ControlBar(self)
        self.control_bar.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="SNWE")

        self.connect_btn = Button(self, text="Connect")
        self.connect_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)

        self.log = Text(self)
        self.log.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="NSWE")
        
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Yeah I've tried exactly that and that doesn't change anything.

Comment: If I add that to something inside the notebok it works. But it's not really the intetion here, I just want to notebook itself to fill the window.

Comment: You need to set `weight=1` for row 0 column 0 using `.rowconfigure()` and `.columnconfigure()` on the parent of the notebook.

Comment: When sorting out layout problems with multiple frames/toplevels, it helps to set their backgrounds to garish colours so you can easily see which ones are not behaving as expected.